# jqgrid - filter not working on some columns

Tags: jqgrid

In the below grid, filtertooblar works for few columns and does not for few other.
I have verified that index and name for colModel is same for the columns for which filtering is not working.
The filters are coming through correctly when I check it in beforesearch event.
Here is one of the colModels that does not filter:

7:
formoptions: {label: 'If Yes to previous question,  would your familiari… affect how you view this case or those involved?'}
frozen: false
index: "ifyestopreviousquestionwouldyourfamiliaritywiththeparticipantsaffecthowyouviewthiscaseorthoseinvolved"
name: "ifyestopreviousquestionwouldyourfamiliaritywiththeparticipantsaffecthowyouviewthiscaseorthoseinvolved"
search: true
sortable: true

And the filter is coming as below
{"groupOp":"AND","rules":[{"field":"ifyestopreviousquestionwouldyourfamiliaritywiththeparticipantsaffecthowyouviewthiscaseorthoseinvolved","op":"cn","data":"Yes"}]}

Can you please help? Thank you very much

```
  var grid = $("#list-grid").jqGrid({
                    datatype: "local",
                    height: 'auto',
                    colNames: colNames,
                    colModel: colModels,
                    data: rows,
                    gridview: true,
                    sortable: true,
                    autowidth: true,
                    shrinkToFit: false,
                    editable: true,
                    scrollOffset: true,
                    ExpandColClick: true,
                    viewsortcols: [true, 'vertical', true],
                    loadonce: true,
                    onSelectRow: function() {
                    return false;
                        },
                        search:
                        {
                            caption: "Search...",
                            Find: "Find",
                            Reset: "Reset",
                            odata: ['equal', 'not equal', 'less', 'less or equal', 'greater', 'greater or equal', 'begins with', 'does not begin with', 'is in', 'is not in', 'ends with', 'does not end with', 'contains', 'does not contain'],
                            groupOps: [{ op: "AND", text: "all" }, { op: "OR", text: "any" }],
                            matchText: " match",
                            rulesText: " rules"
                        },
                    caption: '<h4>Report</h4>',
                    regional: 'en',
                    ondblClickRow: function(rowid) {
                        jQuery(this).jqGrid('viewGridRow', rowid);
                    },
                        loadComplete: function() {
                        var $this = $(this), ids = $this.jqGrid('getDataIDs'), i, l = ids.length;
                        for (i = 0; i < l; i++)
                        {
                            $this.jqGrid('editRow', ids[i], true);
                        }
                    },
                    sortable:
                    {
                        update: function(permutation) {
                    }
                },
                    pager: "#pager"
                }).navGrid('#pager', { view: true, del: false, edit: false, add: false, search: false, refresh: false,width: 800 },
                    {view:false}, // Edit Options
                    { view: false}, // Add Options
                    {},  // Del Options
                    { width: 800 }, // Search Options
                    {
                        closeOnEscape: true,
                        width: 1000,
                        beforeShowForm: function($form)
                        {
                            console.log('form', $form);
                            $form.find("td.DataTD").each(function() {
                            var html = $(this).html();  // &nbsp;<span>&nbsp;</span>
                            if (html.substr(0, 6) === "&nbsp;")
                            {
                                $(this).html(html.substr(6));
                            }
                        });
                        }
                    } // View Options
                    ).filterToolbar({
                        groupOp: 'AND',
                        defaultSearch: 'cn',
                        searchOnEnter: true,
                        searchOperators: false,
                        stringResult: true,
                        ignoreCase: true,
                        
                        beforeSearch: function () {
                            var postData = $("#list-grid").jqGrid('getGridParam', 'postData');
                            console.log(postData);
                        }
                        });
                          
                //grid.data = row; // replace the data array to another data
                //$("#list-grid").trigger("reloadGrid", { current: true });
                //$("#list-grid").jqGrid('setFrozenColumns');      
                
            },
        });
        $("#list-grid").on("jqGridToolbarBeforeSearch", function (e) {
            
            var filters = $(this).jqGrid("getGridParam", "postData").filters;
            console.log(filters);
            if (typeof filters === "string") {
                filters = $.parseJSON(filters);
            }
            return e.result; // forward the result of the last event handler
        });

        </text>
        }
    });
```

Comment: It is really difficult to read your code. The important part here is the colModel, which you do not have published. The best if you want a help is to prepare a online demo (you can use [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net)

Comment: Thank you. But I am unable to create this in jsFiddle. I had provided one of the colModels in my earlier question. Adding it again in this comment. 7:
formoptions: {label: 'If Yes to previous question,  would your familiari… affect how you view this case or those involved?'}
frozen: false
index: "ifyestopreviousquestionwouldyourfamiliaritywiththeparticipantsaffecthowyouviewthiscaseorthoseinvolved"
name: "ifyestopreviousquestionwouldyourfamiliaritywiththeparticipantsaffecthowyouviewthiscaseorthoseinvolved"
search: true
sortable: true

Comment: I'm not 100% sure, but column name could not be so long. Try with shorter name - i.e 10-15 symbols. Note that the column  name (index) is a part of property of the object, which may cause the problem

Comment: Thank you very much Tony. Initially I had also thought that column name being so long could be the problem. But as I was able to filter in another column  whose column name was very long too, I had not investigated more in those lines. Now after your comment, I shortened the column name. all filters work with column length up to 35 characters.  However as I wanted the entire long column name to be shown in the grid, as a workaround I am dynamically changing the column name after the grid is loaded by using setLabel. This fixed all the problems. Thanks a ton. Appreciate your timely help.